# Enterprise message forum/board software and MS Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, messageboard

Is there any message forum/board software (open source or commercial) that allows one to post a question from MS Outlook? I read Kubi Software Inc had this feature. However, a google search for their website seems like the company is no more.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of exchange folders is similar. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer, obviously, but I'll suggest you reading more about Google Groups, that acts, for some specific cases, as a forum software:

http://www.forum-software.org/google-groups/review